# Can CSS be used to make standard plus and minus signs the same width?

Tags: css, number-formatting, typography

Often, in proportional typefaces, normal plus and minus signs (U+002B and U+002D) are different widths:

- +100
- -100

As a result, numbers with a mix of signs don't align properly when left-aligned, and when right-aligned, although they align, the difference in the visual 'mass' of the sign is displeasing.

The effect is worse in certain fonts; for me, Stack Overflow is in Liberation Sans, where the difference is modest, whereas my default serif font is DejaVu Serif, where it is substantial.

I would like to make the plus and minus signs the same width, and visually balanced.

One approach here is to use a proper minus sign (U+2212) which is the same width as a normal plus (U+002B). However, this is not used by the standard formatting and parsing functions in any language i know; using it would be a pain, and could break copy-and-pasting. I would rather not do this.

Is there any way to use CSS to indicate that the normal hyphen-minus sign (U+002D) should be displayed as a minus rather than a hyphen?

`font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;` doesn't seem to do it (there is no particular reason to think it should, but it was worth a try!).

Comment: Isn’t that what mono-type fonts are for?

Answer (score 2):

Use a monospace font family when displaying those characters. That way, they will line up vertically the way you want. Here is an example font stack for sans-serif monospace fonts:

```
font-family: 'Menlo', 'Lucida Console', 'Monaco', 'Consolas', monospace;
```

Use in HTML:

```
<style>
.monospace{
    font-family: 'Menlo', 'Lucida Console', 'Monaco', 'Consolas', monospace;
}
</style>

<div class="monospace">
-100<br/>
+99<br/>
-483
</div>
```